# EntityFieldQuery - Using FieldCondition

Tags: 7, database

**Problem**

I'm trying to locate a node using EntityFieldQuery. Using fieldCondition removes all of my search results. What am I doing wrong?

**So Far**

I've built my function using [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708). It's running in a custom form submit.

```
function mymodule_form() {

   $query = new EntityFieldQuery();

   $query
     ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
     ->entityCondition('bundle', 'contact_details')
     ->fieldCondition('field_user_reference_manual', 'value', '154');

   $result = $query->execute();

}
```

If I remove the fieldCondition query line it returns both contact_details nodes that I've created. One has `field_user_reference_manual = 154` the other `140`

The important values in my MySQL table are:

Field: `field_data_field_user_reference_manual`

Column: `field_user_reference_manual_value`

Comment: From the description you're using a text field to hold a reference to a user - are you absolutely sure the field type isn't user_reference or entity_reference?

Comment: Yep it's an integer field. I put manual in the field so I wouldn't get confused. I also have a user_reference field but that's called `field_user_permission`. (I admit perhaps not the best naming scheme). I've tried the query with other fields on `contact_details` including a text one but none of them work.

Comment: Hmm, if the field name and column name are correct then your code is also correct - to rule out a permissions issue, try adding `$query->addMetaData('account', user_load(1))` before it executes and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Thank you so much, you've now saved my terrible day twice. I'm a little confused though, why would a query run in a module have permissions issues? Does it inherit the permissions of the user it's run by? (By chance I've been testing this on a non-administrator account)

Comment: Certainly does, it's a very handy feature...unless you don't know about it ;) I've just found a duplicate of this actually so I'll close this to point at the other one - it's got a couple of good answers, no point in reproducing them here. BTW if you're just getting into Drupal development I'm sorry to say you'll probably have a few more of these days, the learning curve is pretty steep. The payoff is worth it though!

Comment: Ha, yes I think I've had several of them since I started a couple months ago. I also get constant adverts for Drupal training now because I watched so many Youtube tutorials :)